# Querying an orient-db index on embedded list

Tags: orientdb

How do I query an index on an embedded list of strings. I tried the following, but it did not return any results.

```
select from index:Customers.cities WHERE key = 'delhi'
```

But querying the class directly below worked and it used the same index which I tried above.

```
select from Customers WHERE cities = 'delhi'
```

"Cities" is an embedded list of string in the class Customers. Customers.cities is a NOTUNQIUE index on cities.

Comment: which version of OrientDB?

Comment: seems a bug on 
select from index:Customers.cities WHERE key = 'delhi'
with Embedded list

Comment: i've opened an issue here

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4951

Comment: just closed the issue. Will be available in the next 2.1.3 release